# In Angular2 how do I not call method until other object properties are populated

Tags: angular

Using Angular2 I'm trying to not call the setGroups() method until the properties for 'itemU' are populated. The properties are populated by api calls within a method called setMyData().

**How do I call this.setGroups() after these properties are populated?**

```
//inside of ngOnInit()
    this.myService.getMyData(this.userId)
            .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
            .subscribe(user => this.setMyData(user));

      if(this.itemU.gr1 || this.itemU.gr2 || this.itemU.gr3){
        this.setGroups();
      }
//properties are getting set after the break point passes the if(this.itemU.gr1..
```

**setMyData** populates the properties *this.itemU.gr1 || this.itemU.gr2 || this.itemU.gr1* via the api calls..

```
//outside of ngOnInit()
  setMyData(user: models.ListOfResponse) {
    this.itemU = objectSample[0];

   //sets gr1 
   this.myService.get1(this.u.id )
      .subscribe(access => this.setA(access));  

   //sets gr2
    this.myService.get2(this.u.key, true)
      .subscribe(
        groups => this.hasPerms(groups, false)
        ,error => this.isUnavailable = true
      );                   

   //set gr3
    this.myService.get2(this.u.key, true)
      .subscribe(
        groups => this.hasPerms(groups, true)
        ,error => this.isUnavailable = false
      ); 
  }
```

here is an example of what method 'hasPerms()' does:

```
hasPerms1(groups: models.Stuff[], isTrue: boolean){
 if(isTrue){this.itemU.gr2 = groups;}
 else{ this.itemU.gr3 = ""}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use *rxjs*' `BehaviorSubject`:

```
itemUPopulated$ = new BehaviorSubject(false); 

this.myService.getMyData(this.userId)
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
        .subscribe(user => this.setMyData(user));

itemUPopulated$.subscribe(populated => {
  if (populated) {
    this.setGroups();
  }
});
```

and now later in your code whenever itemU is populated just execute

```
itemUPopulated$.next(true);
```

probably within your `hasPerms1()` function:

```
hasPerms1(groups: models.Stuff[], isTrue: boolean) {
  if (isTrue) {
    this.itemU.gr2 = groups;
    itemUPopulated$.next(true);
  }
  else { 
    this.itemU.gr3 = "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do Observable.forkJoin on get2 and 3 and then execute setGroups(). Still this.setA seems like it has to be executed before. That's why forkJoin is inside get1.

```
setMyData(user: models.ListOfResponse) {
  this.itemU = objectSample[0];

  //sets gr1 
  this.myService.get1(this.u.id )
    .subscribe(access => {
      this.setA(access)

      Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
        this.myService.get2(this.u.key, true),
        this.myService.get2(this.u.key, true)
      )      
      .subscribe(
        groups => {
          // here groups is an array so execute this.hasPerms(groups, false) in a loop
          // then call this.setGroups(); as everything is completed now
        }
        ,error => this.isUnavailable = true
      );                   
    });
```

}